# Set up a shopping cart rule that only applies if 2 specific products are in the cart

Tags: magento-1.9

I am trying to **set up a code** where it is only valid, IF **two products are in the cart**.

Comment: put some code or some more content that what you have did & where you get stuck so that someone can help you

Comment: Try adding more description show some code if you have tried anything. This will help others to get your question and provide you with an answer.

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
$cart_quantity= Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCart()->getItemsCount();
if($cart_quantity==2){ // here is your code }
```